# How react form validation works?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am following tutorial and trying to validate react form but it is not working. I didn't add import, export,CSS code here. I have CSS for input boxes and error message which will appear under input box if error occurred.  I have function handleSubmit which will trigger after submission of form. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.

```
const initialState = {
    fname: "",
    lname: "",
    email: "",
    fnameError:"",
    lnameError:"",
    emailError:""
 }
class NewContactBoot extends Component{
    state = initialState;
    handleChange = event => {
       const isCheckbox = event.target.type === "checkbox";
       this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: isCheckbox ? event.target.checked : event.target.value
       });
   }; 
   
validate = () => {
    let fnameError = "";
    let lnameError = "";
     let emailError = "";

       if(!this.state.fname) {
        fnameError = "name cannot be blank";
       }

     if(this.state.email.includes('@')){
         emailError = 'invalid email';
     }
     if(emailError || fnameError) {
         this.setState({ emailError, fnameError });
         return false;
     }
     return true;
};


   handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const isValid = this.validate();
        if (isValid){
            console.log(this.state);
            this.setState(initialState);
        }     
   };

  render(){
         return(
           <Fragment>
    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 contact-us-section-input">
          <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 contact-us-section-input-box">

            <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                 <input type="text" 
                        name="fname"
                        value={this.state.name} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                        <span>First Name</span> 
                        <div className="error">{this.state.fnameError}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
               <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <input type="text" 
                          name="lname"
                          value={this.state.name} 
                          onChange={this.handleChange}                  
                         />
                  <span>last Name</span> 
                  <div className="error">{this.state.lnameError}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>    

            <div className="row col-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6 ">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <input type="text"  required="required" />
                  <span>Country</span> 
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <div className="input-group Form-main">
                  <input type="email"  
                         name="email"
                         />
                  <span>Email</span> 
                  <div className="error">{this.state.emailError}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div> 
            <div className="col-md-4 col-lg-3 contact-us-section-send-btn">
              <Button className="btn btn-light" type="submit">Submit <i class="fas fa-paper- 
              plane"></i></Button>
           </div

       </div>
    </div>
</Form>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific than "it isn't working"? What isn't working? Is there an error message? We need more details.

Comment: No error message showing up underneath the input box. If I write error message at the initial state it will show up for all the time but error message should show up only is there is error.

Comment: I meant, error messages in the console log caused by bugs in the code.

Comment: No error message in console log also. Nothing ( first name, last name or email) is getting in console log also.

Comment: You seems to be using bootstrap. React-bootstrap Form element has the `validated` prop. You should check it out: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation. Much cleaner approach in my opinion.

Comment: Could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces the issue you have? This way we can run and debug it live.